# How do you list all the namespaces in an instance of TCL?

Tags: namespaces, tcl, introspection

How do you list all the namespaces loaded in an instance of tclsh?

Chenz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running this proc from the TCLer's [Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1489)

```
    proc listns {{parentns ::}} {
        set result [list]
        foreach ns [namespace children $parentns] {
                eval lappend result [listns $ns]
                lappend result $ns
        }
        return $result
    }
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
% listns
::platform ::activestate::teapot::link ::activestate::teapot ::activestate ::tcl
::clock ::tcl::info ::tcl::dict ::tcl::tm ::tcl::mathop ::tcl::unsupported ::tcl
::mathfunc ::tcl::chan ::tcl::string ::tcl
%
```

So, to get ALL namespaces, you simply need to do this:

```
set all_namespaces [concat [listns] "::"]
```

Comment: @schlenk Not really; whole-tree traversal isn't very nice when it comes to tail-call optimization. `lappend result {*}[listns $ns] $ns` would be an improvement though (and only requires the widely-deployed 8.5).

Comment: it doesn't list the :: ... it also only list the children of ::, are there any other namespaces not under ::?

Comment: @CrazyChenz :: is the root namespace. Does it not answer your question?

Comment: I've edited the question to show how to use the proc to find ALL namespaces. Let me know if you need any more information.