# .tbc to .tcl file

Tags: tcl

this is a strange question and i searched but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

I have a compiled `tcl` file i.e. a `.tbc` file. So is there a way to convert this `.tbc` file back to `.tcl` file.

I read [here](http://objectmix.com/tcl/15823-tbc-decompiler.html) and someone mentioned about `::tcl_traceCompile` and said this could be used to disassemble the `.tbc` file. But being a novice tcl user i am not sure if this is possible, or to say more, how exactly to use it.

Though i know that tcl compiler doesn't compile all the statements and so these statements can be easily seen in `.tbc` file but can we get the whole `tcl` back from `.tbc` file.

Any comment would be great.

Comment: You are aware that _the whole point_ of using the .tbc format is to stop conversion to a readable .tcl file. It's certainly not done for performance; it's actually faster to not use the .tbc format at all. (Weird, but true!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, or at least not without a lot of work; you're doing something that quite a bit of effort was put in to prevent (the TBC format is intended for protecting commercial code from prying eyes).

---

The TBC file format is an encoding of Tcl's bytecode, which is not normally saved at all; the TBC stands for **T**cl **B**yte**C**ode. The TBC format data is only produced by one tool, the commercial “Tcl Compiler” (originally written by either Sun or Scriptics; the tool dates from about the time of the transition), which really is a leveraging of the built-in compiler that every Tcl system has together with some serialization code. It also strips as much of the original source code away as possible. The encoding used is unpleasant; you want to avoid writing your own loader of it if you can, and instead use the `tbcload` extension to do the work.

You'll then need to use it with a custom build of Tcl that disables a few defensive checks so that you can disassemble the loaded code with the [`tcl::unsupported::disassemble`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/21445) command (which normally refuses to take apart anything coming from `tbcload`); that command exists from Tcl 8.5 onwards. After that, you'll have to piece together what the code is doing from the bytecodes; I'm not aware of any tools for doing that at all, but the bytecodes are mostly fairly high level so it's not *too* difficult for small pieces of code.

There's no manual page for `disassemble`; it's formally unsupported after all! However, that wiki page I linked to should cover most of the things you need to get started.

Comment: Also, `tcl_traceCompile` won't help very much as the code is already compiled, _and_ there are checks in place even when that feature is enabled to prevent revealing the contents of TBC-defined code. (`tcl_traceExec` is slightly more relevant, but no more useful really.)

Answer (score 0):

I can say partially "yes" and conditionaly too. That condition is if original tcl code is written in namespace and procs are defined within namespace curly braces. Then you source tbc file in tkcon/wish and see code using info procs and namespace command. Offcourse you need to know namespace name. However that also can be found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833761/how-do-you-list-all-the-namespaces-in-an-instance-of-tcl shows how namespaces can be listed. Get the namespaces before loading the tcb module. Get them again after loading it, Then filter the previous from the current. Then use [info commands $namespace] to list out the available functions. Function prototypes are not copyright-able. Tangent: If you have to get what the source code is doing, I suggest using a two person system. Look into how reactos was legally developed.